# Create a global Toast method to use it across all activities?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-toast

I want to create a global shortToast and longToast method to use it dynamically in all other activities I have, so I don't have to define the Toast method in every activity.

I've tried this, but Android Studio tells me that this is a memory leak:

```
public static Activity thisActivity = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    thisActivity = this;    
}

public static void shortToast()
{       
  Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "message" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public static void longToast()
{       
  Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "message" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

What can I do instead to achieve this goal having a global toast method (without memory leak)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Utils class:

```
public class Utils {

    public static void showToast(String msg, Context ctx) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

use it from Activity:

```
Utils.showToast("Message", this);
```

From Fragment:

```
Utils.showToast("Message", getActivity());
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `Activity` as a parameter to `shortToast()` and `longToast()`.

Or, put these methods in a subclass of `Activity`, and have all your activities inherit from it. Then, you can get rid of the `static` keyword from the methods and the `thisActivity` field, and simply use `this`.